# Salesforce package installed with Call Center missing fields

Tags: salesforce, crm, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-service-cloud, amazon-connect

I've created a beta release package that includes a call center definition file and a visualforce page. After creating the package and installing it in a developer org, the visualforce page appears fine, but ALL fields from the call center definition file are missing.

Here is my call center definition file:

```
<callCenter>

<section sortOrder="0" name="reqGeneralInfo" label="General Info">
   <item sortOrder="0" name="reqInternalName"
         label="Internal Name">callCenter001</item>
   <item sortOrder="1" name="reqDisplayName"
         label="Display Name">My Call Center</item>
   <item sortOrder="2" name="reqDescription"
         label="Description">Located in San Francisco, CA</item>
    <item sortOrder="3" name="reqProgId"
         label="CTI Connector ProgId">MyAdapter.MyAdapter.1</item>
    <item sortOrder="4" name="reqVersion" 
         label="Version">4.0</item>
    <item sortOrder="5" name="reqAdapterUrl" 
         label="CTI Adapter URL">http://localhost:11000</item>
</section>

<section sortOrder="1" name="ServerInfo" label="CTI Server Info">
   <item sortOrder="0" name="HostA"
         label="Host A">Host A</item>
   <item sortOrder="1" name="PortA"
         label="Port A">Port A</item>
   <item sortOrder="2" name="HostB"
         label="Host B">Host B</item>
   <item sortOrder="3" name="PortB"
         label="Port B">Port B</item>
   <item sortOrder="4" name="PeripheralID"
         label="Peripheral ID">1000</item>
</section>

<section sortOrder="2" name="DialingOptions" label="Dialing Options">
   <item sortOrder="0" name="OutsidePrefix"
         label="Outside Prefix">1</item>
   <item sortOrder="1" name="LongDistPrefix"
         label="Long Distance Prefix">9</item>
   <item sortOrder="2" name="InternationalPrefix"
         label="International Prefix">01</item>
</section>

</callCenter>
```

After upload it displays fine in the packager org, but when i install the beta package in a dev org, it looks like this:

[image: empty call center fields]

Why does it keep losing the fields I create in the call center definition file after installing in a new org?

Answer (score 0):

This relates to a **bug which was fixed in Summer '22 patch 15.1**.

ref: [CTI Call Center Definition Settings are missing after package installation](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001cSsgQAE)

The current Workaround is to import a Call center definition XML file directly into Salesforce using the UI:

```
Setup > Call Centers > click "Import" button and upload the Call center xml file.
```